# How can I download facebook video using python

Tags: python, facebook

I'm making a facebook messenger chat bot using [fbchat](https://fbchat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Now I want to add facebook video download feature. I want to input the video url and get back the src download url as return.

I tired to add some thirdparty API's but non of them works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

def download_facebook_video(url, save_path):
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
    print("Video downloaded successfully!")
else:
    print("Failed to download video.")

# Example usage
video_url = '<YOUR_FACEBOOK_VIDEO_URL>'
save_file_path = '<PATH_TO_SAVE_VIDEO>'
download_facebook_video(video_url, save_file_path)
```

**Make sure you have necessary permission from Facebook to download videos**